# How to write a cell array to csv in Matlab while keeping the structure of the cell array for the strings

Tags: matlab, csv, cell-array

I am trying to write out a cell aray to a csv file in Matlab. data{1,:} is equal to headers and data{2,:} has the data (2x23).
The data in the cell array has a mixture of strings and numbers.
One of the cells in the array has a very long string/comment and when I try to write it out to a csv, the string gets broken up into a number of pieces and printed out over 3 cells in the csv file. This pushes all of the other information out of sync with it's associated header.
This is what I'm currently trying:

```
 fid = fopen('test.csv', 'w') ;
fprintf(fid, '%s,\t', csvdata{1,1:end}) ;
fprintf(fid,'\n,%f, %f, %f,%f, %f, %s,%s, %f, %f,%s, %f, %s,%s, %f, %s,%s, %s, %s,%s, %s,%s,%s,%s',csvdata{2,:});
fclose all
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enclose your strings with double quotes (`"`) to ensure that the commas within the strings are treated as literal commas rather that delimiters

```
fprintf(fid,'\n,%f, %f, %f,%f, %f, "%s","%s", %f, %f,"%s", %f, "%s","%s", %f, "%s","%s", "%s", "%s","%s", "%s","%s","%s","%s"',csvdata{2,:});
```

Comment: wow! so simple. How did I not know that! What's interesting is that if I put these double quotes for all the %s cells and some of them are empty, they write out the quote marks to the csv file?

Comment: @new2matlab yes that's the expected behavior. the `"`'s are literal quotes that are inserted into your string.